# Pass a closure to replace delegation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have used blocks to get callbacks from other classes. I am a beginner in swift. So I need to find a way to define a closure in one class and assign it to a closure variable in another class. I will be calling this closure to get callback of second class in first class.

What I want is something like this,

```
Class A {

     func viewdidload() {
       let b:B = B()
       b.closure(string:NSString) = {
            print string
         }
     }

}



class B {
       var closure(NSString);

       func () {
          closure(string)
       }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, but you should really [learn Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) first

```
class A {
    func viewdidload() {
        let b = B()
        b.closure = { str in
            print(str)
        }
    }
}



class B {
    var closure : ((String) -> Void)?

    func t() {
        closure?("hi")
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor addendum: as of Swift 3, the input type of function types need to be wrapped in parentheses, e.g., `(String) -> Int` rather than `String -> Int`.

Comment: in class B for closure declaration, replace by this code `var closure: ((String) -> Void)?` Swift 4.2+ compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a Playground:

```
class B {
    var closure: (NSString) -> NSString

    init() {
        closure = { input in
            return "NSString from closure: \(input)"
        }
    }

}

class A {

    init() {
        let b:B = B()
        print(b.closure("hello from A"))
        b.closure = { input in
            return "NSString from another closure: \(input)"
        }
        print(b.closure("hello from A"))

    }
}

A();
```

will print

```
NSString from closure: hello from A
NSString from another closure: hello from A
```